# How to end a dialog and start an another dialog?

Tags: node.js, botframework

```
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, [
function (session, args, next) {
    if (!session.userData.name) {
        session.beginDialog('profile');
    } else {
        next();
    }
},
function (session, results) {
    session.send('Hello %s!', session.userData.name);
}]);bot.dialog('profile', [
function (session) {
    builder.Prompts.text(session, 'Hi! What is your name?');
},
function (session, results) {
    session.userData.name = results.response;
    session.endDialog();
}]);
```

The above code is taken from the Microsoft bot framework documentation. Here, I cant understand the purpose of the session.endDialog(). After running this code, it asks for username and gets the input and replies back with "hello user input". What happens is, it keeps looping again and again.
I want to start the qnamaker dialog after getting the user name and it should continue with the qnamaker  and should not get back to the first function where user name is asked.

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you want to start a new dialog, use `session.beginDialog("dialogName")`. See [understanding dialogs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-overview) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

`session.endDialog()` will end the current dialog (in your example code, it would end the profile dialog), and returns control to the dialog that called it, so (in your example) control would return to the default dialog that launches after the wake word is sent.

The example code that you took from the Microsoft site is just meant to show a basic example, so of course it just has those few dialogs. For the QnA bot you want to build, instead of simply echoing the name back to the user, you would want to start your QnA functionality/dialog in that function, which could include starting another dialog, depending on how you want to architect it.